# Announcements Tiles display limit

Tags: web-part, office-365

This seems like it should be a silly-easy question but for some reason it has me stumped. I have a page with an Announcement Tiles web part on it, and have several items added to it. But the web part only displays one announcement at a time and makes you click to scroll through the rest. I just want it to display them all in a row, preferably bounded by the zone (though a defined number would be fine), but that setting is nowhere to be found in the web part properties, and the only view of the list has a 30-item limit which obviously isn't affecting this. What is limiting this web part to only displaying one tile at a time?

Comment: Anyone find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Search Results & Content Query web part settings has a limit. Try these:

[image]

[image]